# Expanding a variable in find regex

Tags: bash

Is there a way to expand a variable in the below manner? In this case

```
X=$(date --date=yesterday +%Y-%m-%d)
echo $X #--> 2012-07-26
```

The below command works but even if the date is 25,  `$X` is considered as null and picks `*`. Is there a way specifically to expand that variable in place?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*\(/\asyncprocessor.log.'$X'*\|/Renewal.log.'$X'*\|/Scheduler.log.'$X'*\|/smsprocessor.log.'$X'*\|/Subscription.log.'$X'*\).*' -exec ls -ltr {} \;
```

Comment: Also asked on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/q/411797/30957

Answer (score 2):

If you simplify your regex, the problem becomes clearer to spot:

```
'.*/Scheduler.log.'$X'*.*
```

The dot after $X means the last letter can be repeated zero times. Insert a dot before it.

Also, remove the backslash before `a` and probably also the `.*` at the beginning since you are using `maxdepth 1`.

**Update:** This work for me:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex './\(asyncprocessor\|Renewal\|Scheduler\|smsprocessor\|Subscription\).log.'$X'.*' -exec ls -ltr {} \;
```

Comment: Is it true that path should be mentioned in two places ?                find /root/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '/root/\(asyncprocessor\|Renewal\|Scheduler\|smsprocessor\|Subscription\).log.'$X'.*' -exec ls -ltr {} \;

Comment: @mannoj: Read the documentation. Path is optional, if not given, `$PWD` is assumed.

Comment: I had to use on both the places for it to pick the exact path.  thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

the 2012-07-26* in regex mean 2012-07-2 followed by 6 (0 or more times).

Maybe you want 2012-07-26.* (.* : any character 0 or more time)

If $x can contain spaces use double quotes like : "$x"

To be exact the dots . must be escaped \. otherwise they match any character,
and the a character doesn't need to be escaped